# Javascript Semantic UI: Form Validation: list item character not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

Does anyone know why the little dot in the red box at the bottom is not rendering correctly?
As proof that the font is found, see the list above the input box.
[image]

Here's the code, leave the input field empty and click Submit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
    <style>.container {margin: 15em;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>Shows that...</li>
            <li>...it CAN find the character</li>
        </ul>
    <form class="ui form">
        <p>Give this a try:</p>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input placeholder="Your Name?" name="name" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="ui submit button">Submit</div>
        <div class="ui error message"></div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.ui.form').form({
                fields: {name : ['minLength[6]', 'empty']}
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did not see the code that creates the ui error messages, but it looks like a utf8 character is being rendered as ascii. Maybe `<meta charset="utf-8">` could fix it.

Comment: The code you've shown above is working based on this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vhLrw3k/). So it is caused by code you haven't shown.

Comment: Semantic ui is using a :before css rule to place a specialized bullet character instead of the bullet the browser renders using the list-style-type css property. They aren't the same character.

Comment: Bingo @Kevin thank you! (and the others)